# Gpg directory, how to?

Tags: gnupg

How user gpg for encrypt a directory?

example; gpg /home/user/labs-scripts <<< all files in directory or only directory?

thanks for your collaboration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that gpg will only encrypt a single file (or equivalent) the natural solution is to create a gpg encrypted tarball.

First let me show the two step approach.

```
$ tar -C /home/user -cf scripts.tar labs-scripts/
$ gpg -r 0xabcdef -e scripts.tar
```

You can also do it in one sweep, by piping the tar steam.

```
$ tar -C /home/user -cf - labs-scripts/ | gpg -r 0xabcdef -o scripts.tar.gpg -e
```